# How to make two elements scroll at once with one scrollbar in html

Tags: html, css

I'm rewriting a website I made 10 years ago and I would like to have a navigation bar. I realized that last time I integrated some text into the images, but this time I decided to make the text its own element.

It all worked until I defined the scrolling when the images scrolled but the text did not.

I tried fixing this by putting both the text and the images in one larger div, but the whole thing disappeared.

I changed the position in the CSS to "fixed", and it is staying where it needs to be now, but it won't scroll at all.

Here is the code:

```css
div#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #101010;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 235px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/*
.sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
} */

img#thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  height: 125px;
  width: 230px;
}

div#txtoverlay {
  position: fixed;
}

p#overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  left: 150px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fefefe;
  background-color: #10101050;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="sidenav" class="sidenav">
      <div id="sidebar">
         <div id="main">
            <img src="icons/index.jpg" id="thumbnail">
         </div>
         <div id="2008">
            <img src="icons/2008.jpg" id="thumbnail">
         </div>
         <div id="2005">
            <img src="icons/2005.jpg" id="thumbnail">
         </div>
         <div id="2004">
            <img src="icons/2004.jpg" id="thumbnail">
         </div>
         <div id="2001">
            <img src="icons/2001.jpg" id="thumbnail">
         </div>
         <div id="1902">
            <img src="icons/1902.jpg" id="thumbnail">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="txtoverlay">
         <b>
            <p id="overlay">
               Home
            </p>
            <br/>
            <p id="overlay">
               Aug 20
            </p>
            <br/>
            <p id="overlay">
               May 20
            </p>
            <br/>
            <p id="overlay">
               Apr 20
            </p>
            <br/>
            <p id="overlay">
               Jan 20
            </p>
            <br/>
            <p id="overlay">
               Feb 19
            </p>
         </b>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you're looking for ?

```css
div#sidebar {
    background-color: #101010;
    width: 235px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.sidenav {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
/*
.sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
} */

img#thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    height: 125px;
    width: 230px;
}

p#overlay {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #fefefe;
    background-color: #10101050;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    opacity: 100%;
}

div#txtoverlay b {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: 100%;
}

div#txtoverlay b p {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidenav" class="sidenav">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="main">
            <img src="icons/index.jpg" id="thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div id="2008">
            <img src="icons/2008.jpg" id="thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div id="2005">
            <img src="icons/2005.jpg" id="thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div id="2004">
            <img src="icons/2004.jpg" id="thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div id="2001">
            <img src="icons/2001.jpg" id="thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div id="1902">
            <img src="icons/1902.jpg" id="thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="txtoverlay">
        <b>
            <p id="overlay">
                Home
            </p>
            <br />
            <p id="overlay">
                Aug 20
            </p>
            <br />
            <p id="overlay">
                May 20
            </p>
            <br />
            <p id="overlay">
                Apr 20
            </p>
            <br />
            <p id="overlay">
                Jan 20
            </p>
            <br />
            <p id="overlay">
                Feb 19
            </p>
        </b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have been clearer, i would like the images div in a fixed position on the screen, like two individual scrollbars, almost as if it is two iframes next to each other